# Why parfor-loop spend more time than for-loop?

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, matlabpool

```matlab
function test_parfor
N = 1e8;
sum_all = 0; % sum all numbers
sum_odd = 0; % sum odd numbers
sum_even = 0; % sum even numbers
tic;
parfor i = 1 : N
  sum_all = sum_all + i; % sum all numbers
  if mod(i,2)
      sum_odd = sum_odd + i; % sum odd numbers
  else
      sum_even = sum_even + i; % sum even numbers
  end %endif
end %endfor
toc;
fprintf('sum_all=%d,\nsum_odd=%d,\nsum_even=%d.\n', ...
    sum_all, sum_odd, sum_even);
```

I have initialized the parpool envionment and run the codes above. However, the parfor-loop took far more time than single for-loop. Futhermore, the numCores of my PC is 12, and I have initialized 12 workers before runing the function code.
Why? What is wrong with my codes?

Thank you very much! :-)

In addition, the initializing code for parallel computing environment is as following.

```matlab
function initpar(CoreNum)
%Initialize Matlab Parallel Computing Enviornment

if nargin==0
    CoreNum=feature('numCores');
end
if  isempty(gcp('nocreate'))
    clear ALL;
    parpool('local',CoreNum); % matlabpool in R2013
else
    disp('Parallel Computing Enviornment already initialized');
end
```

Comment: parallel computing has "overhead". Have you tried running your loop with more iterations, so that this overhead is outweighted by the potential gains?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this [page](http://www.mathworks.fr/fr/help/optim/ug/improving-performance-with-parallel-computing.html):

> Parallel overhead. There is overhead in calling parfor instead of for. If function evaluations are fast, this overhead could become appreciable. In particular, solving a problem in parallel can be slower than solving the problem serially.

The tip is not to use parfor when each iteration is not time-consuming; the limit of processing cost is of course dependant of your hardware.

EDIT: if you remove the if-else block, the behavior of the loop changes. `sum_all` is now detected as a reduction variable, as it is explained in this [page](http://www.mathworks.fr/fr/help/distcomp/advanced-topics.html#bq_of7_-3). The loop is then correctly broken into independent parts; the partial results are merged at the end. With the if-else block, `sum_even` and `sum_odd` are not considered as reduction variables (I think), so it will behave like a classic for-loop plus the parallel computing overhead.

Comment: Thank you for you reply and document reference.

Comment: When I remove the If-else block in the parfor-loop and remain only the ``sum_all = sum_all + i'', the parfor-loop take much less time than the for-loop. Can you explain why?

Comment: @chentaocuc See my edit. For more information, read carefully all related pages of the doc of Parallel computing in Matlab's doc.

Comment: Thank you very much for your great help! Best wishes!